# Получение обработанных данных с сервера

Tags: javascript, express, greasemonkey

На клиенте я отсылаю данные серверу:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        get_url_ads
// @namespace   afesewvvbbsa
// @include     https://*
// @include     http://*
// @include     http://localhost:8081/ads
// @exclude     https://www.youtube.com/*
// @exclude     https://www.youtube.com/channel/*
// @exclude     /https://(www\.)?youtube\.com/watch\?.*v=([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*/
// @require     http//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
(function (window, undefined) {
    var w;
    if (typeof unsafeWindow != undefined) {
        w = unsafeWindow;
    }
    else {
        w = window;
    }
    if (w.self != w.top) {
        return;
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('get_url_ads');
        var tADS = {};
        tADS['ads'] = window.location.href;
        console.log("tADS_____", tADS);
        var xhrADS = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(tADS),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: 'http://localhost:8585/getJSONPResponse',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('success');
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
            xhrADS.abort();
            for (var prop in tADS) {
                delete tADS[prop];
            }
        }, 2000);
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.close();
        }, 40000);
    });
})(window);
```

На сервере я обрабатываю это запрос с помощью *Express.js* и подключаю *Request.js*, который парсит присланный от клиента URL:

```
var express = require('express'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
app = express(),
fs = require('fs'),
path = require('path'),
underscore = require('underscore'),
request = require('request'),
cheerio = require("cheerio");

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
})); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.post('/getJSONPResponse', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('/ads ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    var headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Super Agent/0.0.1',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
    var options = {
        url: req.body.ads,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers
    }

    if (req.body.ads) {
        console.log('this is ads__', req.body.ads);
        request(options, function (err, response, body) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            else {
                var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                console.log('a find links__', $('body').find('a').length);
                $('body').find('a').each(function (i, e) {
                    var href = $(e).attr('href') + '';
                    if (href.split('https')[1]) {
                        //console.log('a find attr href__',$(e).attr('href'));
                        key['val' + Math.floor(Math.random() * (999 - 1 + 1)) + 1] = href;
                        console.log(key);
                        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
                        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
                        res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                        res.send(JSON.stringify(key)); // отсылаем обратно на клиент
                        res.send(key);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Я хочу отослать распарсенные данные обратно на клиент. Погуглив, я нашел https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180049/parse-jsonp-response-from-express-js-server-clientside-using-greasemonkey, что это можно сделать. Но наткнулся на ошибку которую не могу исправить:

> Can't set headers after they are sent.

Answer (score 1):

у вас там цикл (each) и в каждом проходе вы пытаетесь отправить хедеры (`res.header`) вынесите все res.header в начало обработчика после `app.post('/getJSONPResponse',function( ..){`

**UPD:**

еще вы забыли в конце (после того как всё спарсили и отослали) сделать res.end() - когда исправите ошибку с повторным отсыланием заголовков, у вас вопрос будет висеть пока по tcp таймауту не отвалится

**UPD2:**

```
var express = require('express'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
app = express(),
fs = require('fs'),
path = require('path'),
underscore = require('underscore'),
request = require('request'),
cheerio = require("cheerio");

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
})); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.post('/getJSONPResponse', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('/ads ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    var headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Super Agent/0.0.1',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
    var options = {
        url: req.body.ads,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers
    }
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    if (req.body.ads) {
        console.log('this is ads__', req.body.ads);
        request(options, function (err, response, body) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            } else {
                var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                console.log('a find links__', $('body').find('a').length);
                $('body').find('a').each(function (i, e) {
                    var href = $(e).attr('href') + '';
                    if (href.split('https')[1]) {
                        //console.log('a find attr href__',$(e).attr('href'));
                        key['val' + Math.floor(Math.random() * (999 - 1 + 1)) + 1] = href;
                        console.log(key);
                        res.send(JSON.stringify(key)); // отсылаем обратно на клиент
                        res.send(key);
                    }
                });
                res.end();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: не получается((. Вот если бы обработать запрос app.post('/getResponse..') внутри request(url,..), я думаю что получилось бы?. Опять проблема в асинхронности

Comment: Что не получается? Вангую, что вы res.end() вставили куда-то не туда. Обновил ответ, добавил исправленный вариант

Comment: Опишите симптомы, а то штатный телепат у нас сегодня удаленно работает, не выходит на связь

Comment: Да вы правы не туда поставил. Спасибо за ответ